# Employee Directory in Sharepoint Foundation, fetching info from database

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, directory

I have an existing sql database with all employers, and now after i've created the intranet sharepoint website i want to be able connect the database with the website and then to create an separate web page where i will be able to search for existing employee etc....
Do i have any chance to do that in foundation version?

Thank you very much for your time.

Mihai

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can in Foundation 2010/2013 as it included Business Data Connectivity Services. You'll need to create a service application, then use SharePoint Designer to create the External Content Type. This will depend on the database type, are you using SQL?

There should be plenty online to walk you through how to do this. If not, let me know. HTH